# Need to Avoid htaccess rule on particular folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've searched stackoverflow and numerous websites for an answer to this. So please don't shoot me if it's already been answered on stackoverflow. I am stuck.

I want to Add Slash to a particular url.

```
www.example.com/ppc/photo/sd-xxx to 
www.example.com/ppc/photo/sd-xxx/
```

But I am already using remove slash htaccess code in my htaccess Code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
```

I want to Add Slash on Particular folder urls only, reason they are already added on Adsense, So we don't want to Change that url.

Comment: How many URLs does this apply to? Is `xxx` supposed to represent a variable of some kind? A number? Does it only apply to URLs within `/ppc/photo/...`? It would seem these are not actual "folders" (ie. filesystem directories), but rather just arbitrary URLs. (If they were actual "folders" then you would not need to explicitly exclude them from the rule that removes the trailing slash.)

Comment: Is `/ppc/photo` (or `/ppc`) a physical directory?

Comment: Please update you question to include your complete `.htaccess` file. Specifically, are these "particular URL(s)" being rewritten through a front-controller?

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[.htaccess with dynamic php - subfolder problems](/q/1170880/90527)", "[.htaccess RewriteRule exclude folder](/q/25328546/90527)", "[\[.htaccess\] \[mod-rewrite\] exclude folder](/search?tab=relevance&q=%5b.htaccess%5d%20%5bmod-rewrite%5d%20exclude%20folder)"

Answer (score 0):

You can either add a specific .htaccess in that folder or add [<directory> directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) to your main .htaccess, with the rule you need

Comment: It looks like these URLs should be routed through a front-controller, in which case you can't simply "add a specific .htaccess in that folder" (if indeed it is a physical directory) as it would override the parent directives that internally rewrites the request to the front-controller. And `<Directory>` directives are not permitted in an `.htaccess` context. The `.htaccess` file itself is effectively the `<Directory>` container.

Comment: @MrWhite you can still use per directory rule which add the extra slash but still trigger the main index.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following near the top of the root `.htaccess` file:

```
# Identify specific URLs to which a trailing slash should be added
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ppc/photo/sd-xxx [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/ppc/photo/another
RewriteRule ^ - [E=ADD_TRAILING_SLASH:YES]

# Add slash to specific URLs
RewriteCond %{ENV:ADD_TRAILING_SLASH} =YES
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# Remove slash on other URLs
RewriteCond %{ENV:ADD_TRAILING_SLASH} !=YES
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

The first rule sets an environment variable if one of the URLs is requested that should have a trailing slash appended.

The second rule then adds the trailing slash to one of those URLs, if it has been omitted.

The third rule removes the trailing slash on other URLs. This is similar to your original rule, with an additional *condition* that prevents the rule from being processed when one of your special URLs are requested. I also removed the unnecessary *condition* that tests for the trailing slash and captures the URL-path before the trailing slash and moved this to the `RewriteRule` *pattern* - this is fine providing the `.htaccess` file is in the document root.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing. Since the earlier 301 (permanent) redirect that removed the trailing slash from these URLs will have been cached by the browser. Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues.

---

HOWEVER, this could be simplified if the "particular folder URL(s)" follow a simple pattern that can be summarised with a single regex. eg. URLs of the form `/ppc/photo/sd-xxx`, where `xxx` is any 3 letters/digits (as your example perhaps alludes to). The above could then be reduced to the following:

```
# Add slash to specific URLs
RewriteRule ^ppc/photo/sd-\w{3}$ /$0/ [R=301,L]

# Remove slash on other URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ppc/photo/sd-\w{3}/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```